# To find intersection of clusters in R

Tags: r, k-means

Let's assume I have done several operations and created cluster vectors of  correlation values shown below

```
D <- matrix(rexp(10*10,rate=.1), ncol=10) #create a randomly filled 10x10 matrix
C <- matrix(rexp(10*10,rate=.1),ncol=10)

DCor <- cor(D) # generate correlation matrix
CCor <- cor(C)

DUpper<- DCor[upper.tri(DCor)] # extract upper triangle
CUpper<- CCor[upper.tri(CCor)]

ClusterD <- kmeans(DUpper,3) # cluster correlations
ClusterC <- kmeans(CUpper,3)

ClusterC <- cbind(c(1:45),matrix(ClusterC$cluster)) # add row numbers as column
ClusterD <- cbind(c(1:45),matrix(ClusterD$cluster))
```

I would like to generate a matrix shows the intersection of each cluster group. In this matrix, 5 rows belong to both C1 and D2 group.

[image]

How can I generate a matrix like this?

Comment: You should add a seed to the example to make it more reproducible, since the clustering results are random.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the cbind lines, you could do:

```
table(ClusterC$cluster, ClusterD$cluster)
```